# Return a delegate that leaks implementation details

Tags: c#, design-patterns, delegates

I have a class called `MapBuilder<T>` which internally uses a `Dictionary<PropertyInfo,string>`
The class is used to quickly build up a mapping of which properties will be proxied.
The class looks like this::

```
public class MapBuilder<T>{
    private Dictionary<PropertyInfo, string> m_Map = new Dictionary<PropertyInfo,string>();

    public MapBuilder<T> Add<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property){
        ArgumentValidator.AssertIsNotNull(()=>property);
        var propertyInfo = Reflect.Property<T>.InfoOf(property);
        m_Map.Add(propertyInfo, propertyInfo.Name);
        return this;
    }

    public MapBuilder<T> Add<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property,string columnName){
        ArgumentValidator.AssertIsNotNull(() => property);
        ArgumentValidator.AssertIsNotNull(() => columnName);
        var propertyInfo = Reflect.Property<T>.InfoOf(property);
        m_Map.Add(propertyInfo, columnName);
        return this;
    }

    public Map Compile(){
        return m_Map.TryGetValue;
    }
```

So a user would use it like so::

```
 var map= new MapBuilder<MyClass>()
.Add(x => x.Name)
.Add(x => x.Id)
.Add(x => x.Active)
.Compile()
```

Which would build a map that encapsulates the 3 properties of Name,Id,Active. The problem is that the `Map` delegate can now leak implementation detail to an end user because they can observe the method to be the `TryGetValue` method of a `Dictionary<PropertyInfo,string>` and the target will be the private dictionary. Would you consider this a code smell?

I can wrap this in an anonymous method, but I tend to consider that bad form when a method group conversion is possible.

Comment: What is the peril or damage that occurs if the end user knows this implementation detail?

Comment: Isn't it bad form to break encapsulation? The unscrupulous user could add properties manually to his dictionary, but that's a silly thing anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The level of effort involved in looking at the target and method of your `Map` delegate is about the same as reflecting over the fields of the `MapBuilder` class itself; either way, the caller can discover the private `Dictionary` instance.

I wouldn't worry about it from the point of view of the `MapBuilder` class. Reflecting over private fields would definitely be a code smell: but then it's not your responsibility, but the responsibility of the user of your class.

Comment: Unfortunately, Map since it inherits from `Delegate` exposes both `Method` and `Target`. I think that `Target` being exposed is bad as it is a private field.

Comment: My point is that `MapBuilder`, since it inherits from `Object`, exposes `GetType`, which has a `GetFields` method that users could use to inspect the dictionary. Your concerns could apply to every .NET class you write.